# how to index a numpy array using conditions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
a = np.array([[2,1],
              [4,2],
              [1,3],...]
```

I want to retrieve the elements of the second column where the corresponding elements in the first column match some condition. So something like

```
a[a[:,0] == np.array([2,4]),1] (?)
```

should give

```
np.array([1,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

While this uses `list` to collect results and requires a `for` loop, this collects the second column values once the first column has passed some criteria (in a `list` of acceptable results in this case).

```
a = np.array([[2, 1],
              [4, 2],
              [1, 3]])
b = []
criteria = [2, 4]

for entry in a:
    if entry[0] in criteria:
        b.append(entry[1])

b = np.array(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a mask based off of your first column, and then use that to mask off the second column.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2, 1],
              [4, 2], 
              [1, 3]])

mask = np.logical_or(a[:,0] == 2, a[:,0] == 4)

b = a[:,1][mask]

print(b)
```

Returns:

```
[1, 2]
```

It could get a little clumsy if you have many values you want to compare to.